# Ordenar arreglo de meses en español

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

Estoy generando un arreglo de fechas para llenar un filtro que se usa en una tabla, pero me lo esta trayendo ordenado alfabeticamente. Lo que quiero hacer es ordenarlo por meses. El codigo donde se genera es el siguiente:

```
public function backlog_filtros(){
    //$consulta_status=$this->bd->prepare("SELECT fecha as id,fecha as texto FROM PAT_Tickets_Backlog GROUP BY status ORDER BY field(status,'rechazado','en proceso','por revisar','revisado','interrumpido','nuevo','aprobado')");
    $consulta_fecha=$this->bd->prepare("SELECT fecha as id,fecha as texto FROM PAT_Tickets_Backlog WHERE fecha IS NOT NULL GROUP BY fecha ORDER BY fecha");
    $consulta_proyecto=$this->bd->prepare("SELECT plataforma as id,plataforma as texto FROM PAT_Tickets_Backlog GROUP BY plataforma ORDER BY plataforma");
    $consulta_importancia=$this->bd->prepare("SELECT importancia as id,importancia as texto FROM PAT_Tickets_Backlog WHERE importancia IS NOT NULL GROUP BY importancia ORDER BY importancia");
    $consulta_valor=$this->bd->prepare("SELECT valor_cliente as id,valor_cliente as texto FROM PAT_Tickets_Backlog WHERE valor_cliente IS NOT NULL GROUP BY valor_cliente ORDER BY valor_cliente");
    try{
        $consulta_fecha->execute();
        $filtro['fecha de programacion']=$consulta_fecha->fetchAll();
        $consulta_proyecto->execute();
        $filtro['proyecto']=$consulta_proyecto->fetchAll();
        $consulta_importancia->execute();
        $filtro['importancia']=$consulta_importancia->fetchAll();
        $consulta_valor->execute();
        $filtro['valor percibido por el cliente']=$consulta_valor->fetchAll();
        return $filtro;
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

El arreglo que quiero ordenar es el de "fecha de programacion". El problema es que al imprimirlo lo trae de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y los filtros se generan en el siguiente bloque:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Por favor cambia la imagen por el texto del código, es mucho más fácil de analizar. Y dinos cuáles son los datos en los que tienes problemas. Esto podría resolverse quizá usando objetos `DateTime` que te ordenen por el número del mes o bien ordenarlos desde la consulta.

Comment: Por lo visto los valores de `fecha` son de tipo texto, no de tipo fecha, por lo que solo son ordenables alfabeticamente. Existe otro campo que tenga la fecha en formato numerico?

Comment: Desgraciadamente los campos ya estaban asi cuando empece a trabajar con el proyecto: los guardan como texto y en español. Lo que me sugerian unos compañeros es convertir los textos y luego llenar otro arreglo y eso mandarlo a la vista  pero no encuentro forma de hacerlo

Comment: Tenderías que pensar seriamente en normalizar la tabla, creando una nueva columna del tipo `DateTime` y asignando en ella valores de fecha reales. Mientras tanto, podrías organizar meses y años mediante una función personalizada desde PHP en la que verificas contra un array de meses cuál es el mayor/menor para reordenar los datos. Veo complicado explicarlo en una respuesta porque además de toda la dificultad de un mal diseño (declarando una columna fecha como varchar) veo que lanzas varias consultas basadas en la misma tabla y algo esencial es que no se sabe si la fechas tienen que ...

Comment: ... guardar un orden con respecto a las filas de las otras consultas que están lanzando. Me pregunto precisamente ¿por qué no obtienes todo en una sola consulta?

Answer (score 0):

Para ordenarlo por mes puedes agregar a tu consulta **asc**, para que te traega todo agrupado y por la fecha de menos a mayor... en este caso primero todos los de enero, febrero... etc... y al revez seria con **desc**....Para que empiece por Diciembre, Noviembre...etc...

```
consulta_fecha=$this->bd->prepare("SELECT fecha as id,fecha as texto FROM PAT_Tickets_Backlog WHERE fecha IS NOT NULL GROUP BY fecha ORDER BY fecha asc");
```

Quedo a la espera de tus comentarios si esto te funciono

Comment: Ya lo intente amigo y desgraciadamente no funciona porque el campo en la tabla esta guardado como tipo texto, asi que los trae ordenados alfabeticamente

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar algo así→

consulta_fecha=$this->bd->prepare("SELECT fecha as id,fecha as texto FROM PAT_Tickets_Backlog WHERE fecha IS NOT NULL GROUP BY fecha ORDER BY FIELD (PAT_Tickets_Backlog.fecha ,'Septiembre','Octubre','Noviembre', 'Diciembre', 'Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto')");

Espero que le sirva a alguien

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo funciona este código. Además, dale el formato adecuado, colocando triples acentos graves (```) una línea antes y una después del código. Lee [answer].